# rsync doesn't work from cron with custom "--files-from" parameter

Tags: ssh, cron, find, rsync

I have the script that works perfectly in case of starting from terminal, but it doesn't work from cron

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(date) Starting...
rsync -avR --files-from=<(ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa root@hostA 'find /Data/for_mk/* -type f -cmin -160') root@hostA:/ /
```

crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
*/2 * * * * sh /opt/script.sh >> /var/log/rsync 2>&1
```

log:

```
rsync: failed to open files-from file <(ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa root@hostA find /Data/for_mk/* -type f -cmin -160): No such file or directory
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1435) [client=3.0.9]
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you run it with sh from crontab?
I'm not sure why it is failing, does it work if you place it in /etc/cron.daily/ or /etc/cron.hourly/ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works without 'sh'. Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you added your comment as an answer?

Comment: No Problem! Sure I will add it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `sh`  from:

```
*/2 * * * * sh /opt/script.sh >> /var/log/rsync 2>&1
```

Or replace it with `bash`